# Docker compose nginx image why expose port if not configured

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

```
version: "3"
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    restart: always
  server:
    image: nginx:alpine
    restart: always
  apache:
    image: nginx:alpine
    restart: always
```

This is my `docker-compose.yml`, `port` isn't set but on browser if I type `IPAddress` of each services I can access to "Welcome to Nginx", ¿Why? ¿Is because of version?. This is not a error, I want to know why if every example and docs, says `You must to expose port with -p argument on command or ports on docker-compose file or otherwise you will not be able to access`, what did I misunderstand?

`docker ps`

```
aef0386dfafe   nginx:alpine   "/docker-entrypoint.…"   5 minutes ago   Up 5 minutes   80/tcp    example-app_server_1
a03465500eb7   nginx:alpine   "/docker-entrypoint.…"   5 minutes ago   Up 5 minutes   80/tcp    example-app_apache_1
b6e150e35678   nginx:alpine   "/docker-entrypoint.…"   5 minutes ago   Up 5 minutes   80/tcp    example-app_nginx_1
```

Ignore service name "apache" it's using nginx.

Comment: They are only accessible from the host. You can't access them from outside the host.

Comment: If I use docker (with any image) in localhost (for dev) I don't need to use `port` option?

Comment: You can do it without the port option if you want. The port option lets you access your containers using `localhost:port` rather than `172.17.0.2:port` (or whatever IP your container was assigned) and a lot of people find that more convenient.

Comment: Examples should say it... Most of them say "you must use -p or you wont be able access it" and I trusted, today I forgot to write port and I noticed I could access to server... Arigatou gozaimasu!

Answer (score 2):

As an implementation detail, each container has a Docker-internal IP address.  You can, in principle, directly access it, but only (a) if you're on the same host or the same VM as the container, (b) the host or VM is running native Linux, and (c) you're either outside a container or in the same Docker network.  You seem to be in that exact specific situation, and in that case calling that IP address directly will work.

The correct way to reach the containers, as you note, is to set `ports:` (not `expose:`) for any containers you need to access.  Then, from the same host and outside a container, you can call `localhost` and the first `ports:` number; from a different host you can use the host's DNS name or IP address and the published port.  If Docker is running in a VM (or if you're using the older Docker Toolbox setup) then you can call the VM's IP address.  This setup will work consistently across all host OSes.